# Do switches send their own extra traffic?

Tags: switch

Doing a packet capture I noticed some unknown extra packets that might have come from the switch. Is this what happens and why? Did not see an answer from a quick search. I was under the impression that switches only passed packets around, but did not have their own overhead protocol...

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. STP, CDP, LLDP, OSPF, BGP, etc. could all be running on said switch which would all originate from the switch itself. You'd have to tell us a make and model, maybe a screenshot of these extra packets you see, and probably provide a sanitized config for us to see what all the switch is doing.

Comment: Please edit your question to give examples of what you mean, otherwise we are simply guessing what the traffic is and where it comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s hard to tell for sure since you’ve provided so little information, but commercial grade switches often run Spanning Tree Protocol. That may be what you’re seeing.

Comment: Unknown unicasts and broadcasts, too.

Comment: Isn't guessing at an answer off limits here?

Comment: @JesseP. You're welcome to vote to close.

Comment: I already voted.

Comment: @RonTrunk Also, it comes off as very hypocritical to post a guess as an answer when I've seen you take action on other people for doing the same thing.

Comment: @JesseP.  Fair enough

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to look at the frames in detail.

While simple (=unmanaged) switches only forward incoming frames, managed switches can support a multitude of features and protocols that may cause them to send frames on their own, e.g.

- spanning tree BPDUs (or for shortest path bridging 802.1aq)
- LACP control frames for link aggregation
- GVRP, MVRP for dynamic VLAN propagation
- LLDP or CDP hello frames for device discovery
- ICMP echo requests for SLAs
- DHCP requests or relaying
- SNTP device time updates
- L3 switches can also use various routing protocols for dynamic route exchange including RIP, OSPF, IS-IS, BGP

Comment: Isn't guessing at an answer off limits here?

Comment: @JesseP. Fair point - I think I wasn't guessing, just listing some frames you could expect. ;-)

Comment: Sure, but you posted it as an answer, not a comment, which it's not and can't be without more details from the OP.

Comment: Well, the actual question was *Do switches send their own extra traffic?* for which the answer is *Yes, some do*. Another question was *why?* which I tried to explain. The OP didn't ask "what are those frames I'm seeing?"

Comment: Yes they did.  Re-read their post.  They literally asked " Is this what happens and why?" after saying they saw some oddities in a packet capture.  So, without seeing said packet capture for this specific case, NOBODY can say "yes" or answer why, because there is no info to go off of.  We don't know a brand, we don't know a model, we don't know how the switch is configured, etc.

Comment: What you're quoting is the subject line of the post - not the actual question posed in the post itself.